# How to reduce the size of Docker Image?

Tags: docker

I currently inherited a Docker Image saved in a private registry of size around 250GB. It mainly contains few files of size around 50GB, apart from this all the storage is consumed by the debian 8.2 and the layers of history.

There has been more than 150+ layers of delta.

When I try to squash the image, it fails as the history is not saved properly and docker history is giving me below output

```
IMAGE               CREATED             CREATED BY          SIZE                COMMENT
53252a598183        23 hours ago        /bin/bash           709MB               "asdf"
<missing>           27 hours ago        /bin/bash           10.4MB              "1243"
<missing>           47 hours ago        /bin/bash           2.58GB
```

How do I reduce the image size?

PS: Constructing the image from scratch is not an option as many changes are not tracked

Comment: What commands did you actually run and what was their output? [Docker missing layer IDs in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35310212/docker-missing-layer-ids-in-output) might be relevant. Having that history should be essential and it should be in the build files. If it isn't you're probably using the wrong tool.

Comment: Follow [good practices to build Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).

Comment: @Biswapriyo if he really can't rebuild the image (which seems odd if the latest image was created a day ago) those steps won't help much. Even if I do agree that the best course of action would probably to rebuild the image in a proper way.

Comment: How are you trying to squash the image?

Comment: I followed https://github.com/goldmann/docker-squash for the squash, since the docker image history were missing.

Comment: I have not pasted the complete output of the docker image history as it was very long, first change dates back to 2018 March